# How to change Dropdown Indicator position on react-select

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-select

Is it possible to change Dropdown Indicator to "float" on left (instead of right as default) on a React Select Component?

I was checking Dropdown Indicator [props](https://react-select.com/props#dropdownindicator) on its API but no clues at the moment..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the dropdown indicator to the left by reversing the row order since the container is using `flex`

```js
const customStyles = {
  control: (base) => ({
    ...base,
    flexDirection: "row-reverse"
  })
};
```

```js
<Select
  styles={customStyles}
  options={options}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64255002/how-to-change-dropdown-indicator-position-on-react-select]

Comment: Thanks, that was very clever!

Answer (score 1):

There is an `isRtl` prop for this:

```
<Select<OptionType>
    isRtl
    options={options: OptionType[]}
/>
```

you can find it on their [prop documentation](https://react-select.com/props#select-props)